# accessing in (passing to) django models signal methods like pre_save, pre_delete the request.user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I have to track the history of all of changes, which occure to my models. I also keep track of user making this changes. For now I was dealing with in views.py but I would like to utilitize this functionallity using django signals like `pre_save`, `pre_delete` for each of models.

The question are:

1) what is the best way to access there request.user ?

2) What about using `Django Admin Logs` mentioned here: [Storing user activity in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001444/storing-user-acivities) for accesing user history events?

3) What about the approach of using `CurrentUserMiddleware` mentioned here: 
[Django: Populate user ID when saving a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model)

I find the way in 3) very sexy, but does it have some drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

[This huge list of packages should do the trick](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/)

I personally like the look of:

- DJANGO REVERSION
- DJANGO-SIMPLE-HISTORY
- DJANGO-REVISIONS

because of their rollback functionality.

I can't personally vouch for any of them, not having used them before. Seriously considering changing that though...